# NO VHD - There is currently a lease on the container and no lease ID was specified in the request

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have a empty storage blob. I don't have VMs or Disks anywere, the error:

> There is currently a lease on the container and no lease ID was specified in the request
>
> Workarounds tried
>
> - CloudXplorer, no luck and no release lease, since it's the blob himself

I'm stuck, all threads that i looked for are about VHDs and VMs, simply the BLOB is empty. Anyone had this problem before? any suggestions?

Thanks, Regards
Joao

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311261/cannot-delete-blob-there-is-currently-a-lease-on-the-blob-and-no-lease-id-was-s/16311476#16311476

Comment: @CSharpRocks i don't have any VM or Disks

Comment: What were you doing? When came this error message?

Comment: @PeterKirchner I'm trying to remove a Resource Group that have a storage container and Blob, when deleting the Resource or Blob that is empty, error is fired. As I say before. I don't have VMs or Any disks on my Azure account.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you solve it?

Comment: Try to go to the old portal and remove any refences. They will not appear in the new portal