# How to break a lease on Blob Storage in Azure with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

How do I break a lease on an item in Blob Storage utilizing PowerShell?

I'm receiving the following when trying to upload something over the current image:

```
Add-AzureRmVhd : The remote server returned an error: (412) There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request..
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmVhd -Destination $osDiskUri -LocalFilePath $localFileName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmVhd], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

Comment: I answered a similar question recently, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364494/272109), regarding the inability to break a lease. It's typically due to a Disk object still existing, related to (and having a lease on) the vhd page blob in question. In my answer, I show where to find the list of disks (in old and new portal). If this turns out to be the case, you can likely delete the Disk object via PowerShell as well as via portal.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it ended up being a lot easier to simply release the lease in PowerShell, upload a new VHD to the same exact file name, and start the VM back up.

Comment: [This script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-break-the-locked-c2cd6492#content) as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-cannot-delete-storage-account-container-vhd#lf-content=177489778:625507403) didn't work for me. 

I installed [Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/). Rt.Clicked on the container "Break Lease". And it worked....

Answer (score 7):

Login to the old portal and navigate to the **Virtual Machines** then the **Images** tab the url will be `https://manage.windowsazure.com/@yourname.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/VirtualMachineExtension/images.` Select the image and choose **Delete** on the bottom.

[image]

After that go to your storage and delete it.

You can also try the following which will remove blobs for a given container and then remove the container.

```
Add-AzureAccount
Get-AzureSubscription | Format-Table SubscriptionName, IsDefault, IsCurrent, CurrentStorageAccountName

$SubscriptionName = 'Your subsscription name'
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

Get-AzureSubscription -Default

Get-AzureStorageAccount | Format-Table -Property StorageAccountName, Location, AccountType, StorageAccountStatus

$StorageAccountName = "Your storage account"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName).Primary
$ContainerName = "Your container name"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

#Get a reference to all the blobs in the container.
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Context

#Remove lease on each Blob
$blobs | %{$_.ICloudBlob.BreakLease()}

#Delete blobs in a specified container.
$blobs| Remove-AzureStorageBlob

Remove-AzureStorageContainer -Container $ContainerName -Context $Context
```

If you want to break a seal on a blob you can use the [How to break the locked lease of blob storage in Microsoft Azure (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-break-the-locked-c2cd6492)

Answer (score 3):

```
$key = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $selectedStorageAccount.ResourceGroupName -name $selectedStorageAccount.StorageAccountName -ErrorAction Stop)[0].value 
        $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $selectedStorageAccount.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key -ErrorAction Stop 
        $storageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageContext -Name $ContainerName -ErrorAction Stop 
        $blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container  $ContainerName -Blob $BlobName -ErrorAction Stop          
        $leaseStatus = $blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus; 
        If($leaseStatus -eq "Locked") 
        { 
             $blob.ICloudBlob.BreakLease() 
             Write-Host "Successfully broken lease on '$BlobName' blob." 
        } 
        Else 
        { 
            #$blob.ICloudBlob.AcquireLease($null, $null, $null, $null, $null) 
            Write-Host "The '$BlobName' blob's lease status is unlocked." 
        }
```

If you want to a script for ARM resources you can use the
[How to break the locked lease of blob storage by ARM in Microsoft Azure(PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-break-the-locked-d01ba283)

Answer (score 2):

The lease is likely from something like a VM, or something else using the Blog Storage. As a result manually releasing the lease could cause problems.

With that said, the following PowerShell command should do the trick:

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME" | Get-AzureStorageBlob -name "CONTAINER_NAME").ICloudBlob.BreakLease()
```

If its a VM, you should see the following post on removing the disk:
[Cannot delete blob: There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311261/cannot-delete-blob-there-is-currently-a-lease-on-the-blob-and-no-lease-id-was-s)

However, if you simply want to replace the drive used by every machine that uses the given blob, stopping the VM, releasing the lease, uploading a new image, and starting the VM appears to work.

Comment: You might need the resource group name if you are using `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` and the blob name for `Get-AzureStorageBlob`: 

`Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -Name <storage account name> | Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob <blob name> -Container <container name>).ICloudBlob.BreakLease()`

Comment: Should be noted that this will not work on Premium Storage disks. Only standard ones.