# Receive error "There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified" when trying to delete a leased blob using the C# BlobClient?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a Blob that I am accessing thus:

```cs
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(Container);

BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(key);
BlobLeaseClient blobLeaseClient = blobLeaseClientWrapper.GetBlobLeaseClient(blobClient);

blobLeaseClient.Acquire(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

When I come to delete the blob using:

```cs
blobClient.Delete();
```

I get the error:

> There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request

I've tried breaking the lease but I still get the same error:

```cs
blobLeaseClient.Break();
blobClient.Delete();
```

How do I delete a leased blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be very well documented. The only reference I could find was this [unhelpful response in the MSdocs github site](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56927#issuecomment-645405461) and this old question about [VMs from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311261/cannot-delete-blob-there-is-currently-a-lease-on-the-blob-and-no-lease-id-was-s).

A bit of digging in the classes unearthed this overload that seems to fix the problen:

```cs
 blobClient.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, new BlobRequestConditions()
            {
                LeaseId = blobLeaseClient.LeaseId
            });
```